# What to do when a dependency chain ends? (R install via conda)

Tags: r, anaconda

I am pretty dang stumped on this one. I am attempting to install the R package diceR (https://github.com/AlineTalhouk/diceR) on an HPC system where software must be compiled locally. The way things were setup -- before I came in -- was to try using conda for everything we could. So we have system install of conda, with user environments saved locally (I've heard this is poopoo'd - but hey... I'm just working with what I was given).

In comes diceR. Most R installs are easy easy, create a new R-environment, go into R and do a package.install("package"). I have had the strangest time with this package - circular or dead end dependencies that I can't explain.

I was hoping someone might have experience with something similar and have ideas on next steps. I know this is a niche package, and I'm not necessarily asking to get help on this exact problem - more along the lines of what to do when something like this happens. Below is the "dependency" chain issue I've been having (from CRAN Depends:  R ≥ 3.5)

```
$ conda activate r-env
$ R --version
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) -- "Kick Things"...

$ R

>install.packages("diceR")
```

lots of compilation happens, but enevitabley fails...

```
ERROR: dependency ‘NMF’ is not available for package ‘diceR’
removing ‘/projects/gehi0941/software/anaconda/envs/R_diceR/lib/R/library/diceR’
```

So I try installing NMF...

```
ERROR: dependency ‘Biobase’ is not available for package ‘NMF’
removing ‘/projects/gehi0941/software/anaconda/envs/R_diceR/lib/R/library/NMF’
```

Then Biobase...

```
Warning message:
package ‘Biobase’ is not available for this version of R
```

Then I'm done, I've followed this chain all the way down, right? Talking language/manager agnostic now: what do folks to at this step?

Comment: You need to install the BioConductor Manager first then install the base BioC package then you can install further packages. More complete directions here: https://www.bioconductor.org/install/

Comment: Dang okay, I'll give that a go. Boy that was quick - embarrassingly for me I've spent 2 days on this - can I ask, what led you to that? Was it just prior knowledge of that manager or did I miss something in the docs?

Comment: Just prior knowledge for me but I would have thought that searches on “biobase package” should have pulled up relevant hits.